# How do I assign a texture to a material in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I read the docs and this should work

```
MeshRenderer mesh_renderer = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ();
mesh_renderer.material = Resources.Load<Material> ("MapMaterial");
mesh_renderer.material.mainTexture = Resources.Load<Texture> ("cobblestone");
```

But it assigns an empty default material.

cobblestone.jpg is in the assets folder so it should work right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it will search for the resource you're asking relative to the Assets\Resources folder.

```
// This will search for 'cobblestone' in Assets/Resources/cobblestone.jpg:
mesh_renderer.material.mainTexture = Resources.Load("cobblestone", typeof(Texture2D));
```